# regulate system volume with midi controller

Tags: linux, audio, midi

Make midi controller regulate system volume. With the following code a midi controller can be used for controlling the audio volume of a linux system:

```
aseqdump -p 20 | sed -nur 's/^.*controller 14, value (.*)/\1/p' | \ 
while read l; do amixer -q set Master $l; done
```

Given that the midi controller's client nr is: 20 (this can be determined by `aconnect -i`) and the 'nr' of the treble is 14 (see `aseqdump` output for details)

Is there a way to do this more directly, e.g. in order to circumvent the parsing?

Comment: Not really, something will need to read the MIDI events and take action when an appropriate event is parsed out of the stream.

Comment: You would have to write your own program to receive MIDI messages. Please note that you can use the client name instead of the number.